# VNC with hops multiple machine

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, vnc

I want to acces a remote machine that in inside another machine. I can ssh to it but can't see any in VNC viewer.
That's the configuration.

```
external_ip port 3999 to internal_ip192 port 3999

internal_ip192 port 3999 forwards to internal_ip10 port 22
```

From local_machine:

```
ssh -i mykey -p 3999 ubuntu@external_ip
Connection done.
```

So if now I up vncserver running on port 5901, It's needed to forward this port to internal_ip192 and external_ip?

I tried to do this, but can't see any in VNC viewer:

```
ssh -i mykey -p 3999 -L 5901:localhost:5901 ubuntu@external_ip
(Connection done)
```

Does I need to open port 5901 on external_ip / internal_ip192 and forward this ports?

Answer (score 2):

For one hop using an interim computer called `interim.host`, use the following procedure:

From your workstation:

```
$ ssh -L5900:localhost:5900 user@interim.host
```

From `interim.host`:

```
$ ssh -L5900:localhost:5900 user@remote.host
```

Finally connect your local VNC client to `localhost:5900`.

You may use this procedure to extend to as many hops as required.