# SSH tunnel between three machines A -> B-> C

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I've got three machines.

**A** - my machine, that has access to machine B via ssh but no access to machine C

**C** - another machine that exposes RestAPI on `http://machineCip:1234`

**B** - yet another machine, that has access to RestAPI exposed by machine C (by using `curl http://machineCip:1234/`)

I need machine A to have access to RestAPI exposed by machine C (A -> B -> C)

I tried to setup a ssh tunnel on machine B, but it does not work.

```
ssh -N -f-L 1234:machineCip:1234 userB@machineBip
```

Comment: What's the error message when it doesn't work?

Comment: @IporSircer when I try 
`curl http://machineBip:1234/`
 from machine A, there is an information "Operation timed out"

Comment: This is well-answered in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1361796/vnc-with-hops-multiple-machine), but current post cannot be flagged as duplicate as there are no upvotes.

Comment: On machineB, do you see port 1234 shown as listening by `sshd` if you run `sudo netstat -lptn`?

Comment: Can you run your `ssh` command with `-vv` and show us the logs (edit out IPs, names, and keys, as you'd like)?

Comment: `ssh  -vv` - and I found out that my proxy was blocking tunnel. Thanks @MosheKatz

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `curl http://localhost:1234`, not `curl http://machineB:1234` (as you said you use in your comment).

A port forwarded through SSH appears on the *local* machine, not on the remote machine.

Comment: I tried curl http://127.0.0.1:1234 on machineA and the same error occured

Answer (score 1):

I used `ssh  -vv` (as @MosheKatz adviced) and I found out that my proxy was blocking tunnel. 
Now the problem is resolved.