# Can I set up my Windows 10 machine as an SSH landing?

Tags: windows-10, ssh, remote-desktop

We use Windows 10 desktops at work just as SSH clients into our Linux server, and our server can only accept connections from these machines. When I'm working remotely, I have to RDP into my machine, which is incredibly laggy and unresponsive (1-2 frames per second, typing is horrible). I'd like to just pass SSH over from my home machine, which has a nicer SSH client and fonts available anyway. Is there a way, maybe using Bash On Windows, to configure my work Windows machine as an SSH landing point?

Comment: Are you able to SSH into the machine instead of RDP?  Are you able to configure a VPN into of RDP?  WSL (Bash on Windows) cannot be used to accomplish this task by itself.  You would still be at the mercy of being unable to connect to the Linux server due to your IP address.  Current versions of Windows 10, come with the OpenSSH client, already installed.  Without more information about your setup, and your configuration limitations, I am not sure how to answer your question.  My current answer would simply be "it is possible but entirely depends on your configuration"

Comment: If you can SSH into the work computer, [this solution](https://superuser.com/a/1362016/8672) can let you do the hop.